# jQuery ui position not updating position when scrolling the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery.ui.position Utility to position an element in my page which is working nicely for the most part however when I scroll the page down the element stays in the same position:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $( "#cart-block-contents" ).position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right bottom",
    of: "#cart-block--summary"
  });
  $('#cart-block-contents').hide();
  $("#cart-block-contents").css({"visibility": "visible"});
});
```

I tried updating the position on scroll using this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $( "#cart-block-contents" ).position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right bottom",
    of: "#cart-block--summary"
  });
});
```

But that didn't do the trick and caused the position of the element to increment every time I scroll the page.

Any ideas on how to make it reposition the element every time the page is scrolled?

Thanks in advance.